# Poetry update error when installing cryptography lib on Big Sur

Tags: openssl, macos-big-sur, python-poetry

When running `poetry update` in a `Django` project I get this issue.

```
Package operations: 8 installs, 22 updates, 0 removals

• Updating cryptography (3.4.6 -> 3.4.8): Failed

EnvCommandError

  Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
Building wheel for cryptography (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for cryptography (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/paul/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/jiraglue-VXquq6c2- 
py3.9/bin/python /Users/paul/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/jiraglue- 
VXquq6c2-py
```

I have tried updating pip at the project level as well `/Users/paul/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/jiraglue-VXquq6c2-py3.9/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

But this didn't help. The solutions I found online are for fixing this issue at the system level, by linking `openssl` headers. I tried this as well and installing cryptography was possible. However, my issue is within the virtual env and I am not sure how to resolve it.

Full output later errors with this -

```
    build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/_openssl.c:575:10: fatal error: 
    'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
     #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
...
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: @Myzel394 try to change the terminal and run again. Also make sure you have Rust toolchain installed.